# Serializing Drake objects with Python

Tags: drake

Is there any way to serialize and de-serialize objects (such as 
pydrake.trajectories.PiecewisePolynomial, Expression ...) using pickle
or some other way?

It does not complain when I serialize it, but when trying to load from file
it complains:

```
TypeError: pybind11_object.__new__(pydrake.trajectories.PiecewisePolynomial) is not safe, use object.__new__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a list of classes you would like to serialize / pickle?

I can create an issue for you, or you can create one if you have a list already in mind.

---

More background:

Pickling for `pybind11` (which is what `pydrake` uses) has to be defined manually:
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#pickling-support

At present, we don't have a roadmap in Drake to serialize everything, so it's a per-class basis at present.

For example, for pickling `RigidTransform`: [issue link](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/11957) and [PR link](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/11976)

A simpler pickling example for `CameraInfo`: [PR link](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/12131/files)

(FTR, if an object is easily recoverable from it's construction arguments, it should be trivial to define pickling.

Comment: Classes are PiecewisePolynomial and Expression that is composed from program indeterminates. I was wondering if there's something that could be done as-is. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 so I wouldn't want to update Drake in any case since it is not supported anymore (for the time being). I have ways of saving just the "data" I need to re-create it after loading it back. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a general solution without updating Drake, so yeah, your manual saving of just the "data" is going to be the best way under those constraints. Thanks for the info!